GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync fails to return a token for "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
I am attempting to use the GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync method to generate an access token.
When calling the method as described in the documentation ($SheetsService.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync()).Result, nothing is returned if the scope is related to:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations
However, it succeeds when referencing scopes unrelated to docs.
Example Code
[byte[]]$P12Key = $P12FromFile
$P12KeyPassword = 'notasecret'
$certificate = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::new(
    [System.Byte[]]$P12Key,
    $P12KeyPassword,
    [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable
)

$ServiceAccountCredentialInitializer = [Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential+Initializer]::new('serviceaccount.iam.gserviceaccount.com')
$ServiceAccountCredentialInitializer.Scopes = [string[]]"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
$ServiceAccountCredentialInitializer.User = "impersonatedUser@example.com"
$ServiceAccountCredential = [Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential]::new($ServiceAccountCredentialInitializer.FromCertificate($certificate))


$ServiceInitializer = [Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService+Initializer]::new()
$ServiceInitializer.HttpClientInitializer = $ServiceAccountCredential
$ServiceInitializer.ApplicationName = "Powershell Google Workspace"
$Service = [Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.SheetsService]::new($ServiceInitializer)

#Attempt to use the builtin resource Class
$Service.Spreadsheets.Get('167iXRp_a46lPHMndqUozuu0nQ') #Success


#Attempt to generate Token for this scope
($ServiceAccountCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync()).Result #Returns Nothing


#Attempt to generate Token for non docs/slides/sheets scopes
$ServiceAccountCredentialInitializer.Scopes = [string[]]"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive" #Or any scope that isn't Sheets/Docs/Slides related
$ServiceAccountCredential = [Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential]::new($ServiceAccountCredentialInitializer.FromCertificate($certificate))
($ServiceAccountCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync()).Result #Returns a Token

Update:
The Powershell formatter clobbers information written to the console sometimes. On a whim I coerced the output of $Service.HttpClientInitializer.getAccessTokenForRequestAsync() | select *
and found it is generating the following exception:
Error:"unauthorized_client", 
Description:"Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.", 
Uri:""

For some reason it wasn't written to the error stream. But the message contradicts that, as demonstrated, the service is able to successfully utilize the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets scope when using the builtin resource class.

Can you provide your full existing code with the error you have encountered? This would allow the community to better understand your problem and provide targeted solutions.

not your issue but a recommendation, use .GetAwaiter().GetResult() instead of .Result

@SantiagoSquarzon That generates an error message in the expected manner now interestingly.

Thus my recommendation :)

So I went to check, the scope was not enabled for domain wide delegation, but I have existing automations that were updating spreadsheets. I dug into the Module I was using, PSGsuite, lo and behold, it's calling https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive, which is evidently all that's needed to use $Service.Spreadsheets.Values.BatchGet($SpreadsheetId). My mistake for thinking the sheets API required the spreadsheets scope for interacting with the sheets service. oops.

Sounds like you could post an answer to your question ;)
